# Python boto3 run ECS task conditionally

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-ecs

I am trying to use a python script to run an ECS task, but if there is a task as 'PENDING', 'PROVISIONING' or 'ACTIVATING' not to run it. It seems to work fine, but the script seems to only detect the first result if I have multiple tasks running. Here is a bit of my slightly altered, redacted code:

```
import boto3
import os

client = boto3.client('ecs')
environment = os.environ["ENVIRONMENT"]

list_tasks = client.list_tasks(
    cluster= os.environ["CLUSTER"],
    family='redacted-{}'.format(environment)
)

status = list_tasks['taskArns']
task_status = client.describe_tasks(
    cluster= os.environ["CLUSTER"],
    tasks=list_tasks['taskArns']
)

accepted_status = ['PROVISIONING', 'PENDING', 'ACTIVATING'] 
for task_status in task_status['tasks']:
    print (task_status['lastStatus'])
  
 
    if task_status['lastStatus'] in accepted_status:
        print('task PROVISIONING, RUNNING or PENDING')
    else:
        print('something else')
```

The output of

```
for task_status in task_status['tasks']:
     print (task_status['lastStatus'])
```

seems to give an output of something like:

```
RUNNING
ACTIVATING
RUNNING
```

But doesn't always recognize 'ACTIVATING' is in the response. I'm pretty new to python so excuse me for the lack of intelligence here.

Comment: Please fix your spacing, unless this is your actual code?

Comment: Like I say, fairly new to python so have let the IDE do the work in terms of spacing. Hopefully looks better now. If there's some guidance somewhere regarding standards then that would be really useful too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change indents from

```
for task_status in task_status['tasks']:
    print (task_status['lastStatus'])
  
accepted_status = ['PROVISIONING', 'PENDING', 'ACTIVATING']  
if task_status['lastStatus'] in accepted_status:
    print('task PROVISIONING, RUNNING or PENDING')
else:
    print('something else')
```

to

```
accepted_status = ['PROVISIONING', 'PENDING', 'ACTIVATING']
for task_status in task_status['tasks']:
    print (task_status['lastStatus'])
    
    if task_status['lastStatus'] in accepted_status:
        print('task PROVISIONING, RUNNING or PENDING')
    else:
        print('something else')
```

In your example for loop executing:

```
for task_status in task_status['tasks']:
    print (task_status['lastStatus'])
```

and after that last value of `task_status` applied to

```
if task_status['lastStatus'] in accepted_status:
    print('task PROVISIONING, RUNNING or PENDING')
else:
    print('something else')
```